# Resizable div with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

This question may look stupid for some. My apologies, I am not that savy with CSS.

Now, I have a table with 2 columns (needs to be equal). The table width is put to 100% and needs to be resized with the page.

The header, it's ok. It only contains 2 cells with 2-3 words, so there are no problems.

Now, each of the following cells contain quite some big text and I need to be displayed as it is (no wrapping).

What I did:

```
<style>
.contentDiv
{
        display: inline-block;
        overflow-x:auto;
        overflow-y:hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>

<table style="width:100%">
  <th>
    <tr><td with="50%">head 1</td><td width="50%">head 2</td></tr>
  </th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><div class="contentDiv">big-text-here</div></td>
      <td><div class="contentDiv">big-text-here</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The bottom line is I want the table to have the full width, the inner content-cell to have half of the table width and the text (no matter how big it is) not to alter the layout (scrollbars should appear if the content is bigger than the required surface).

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want each contentDiv to wrap so that they each each take up 50% of the viewport width OR do you want them not to wrap at all such that they display on one (long line - [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/a3yyD/1/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda didn't know what you mean, but I am sure you mean this http://jsfiddle.net/mDXb5/ also you had some problems with your code above that you should edit. e.g:

```
</table> tag is missing instead you use </tr> which is wrong
```

Comment: Thanks for the typo warning. Fixed. Actually, what I need is something similar with the boxes where you edit the code (HTML and CSS boxes). And if it's possible, with horizontal scrollbars, too.

Answer (score 0):

This should eliminate any wrapping.

```
td { position: relative; }
.contentDiv
{
    display: inline-block;
    overflow-x:auto;
    overflow-y:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute; 
}
```